# iOS: How do you find the creation date of a file?

Tags: ios, file, date, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to find the creation date (NOT modification date) of a file.

Creation date doesn't appear to be in the attributes of a file, though modified date is.

I'm using this code..

```
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString* path = [PathHelpers pathInDocumentsFolderWithFilename:FILE_NAME];
NSDictionary* attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];

if (attrs != nil) {
    return (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

This always returns nil.  Typing 'po attrs' into the debugger to get the list of key/value pairs in the NSDictionary returns the following..

> NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 20;
>   NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = staff;
>   NSFileModificationDate = 2010-01-21 11:47:55 +0000;
>   NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
>   NSFileOwnerAccountName = ben;
>   NSFilePosixPermissions = 420;
>   NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
>   NSFileSize = 338;
>   NSFileSystemFileNumber = 2234;
>   NSFileSystemNumber = 42553324;
>   NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;

No creation date.. bah..

Anyone know another way of getting the creation date or does it just not exist in iOS?

Comment: Note that the trace i've shown is from the iphone simulator.  I get the same issue on a real device however - creation date isn't listed.

Comment: The documentation lists NSFileCreationDate as a returned value, s o you might want to file a bug with Apple. It certainly sounds like this isn't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This code actually returns the good creation date to me:

```
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary* attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];

if (attrs != nil) {
    NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];
    NSLog(@"Date Created: %@", [date description]);
} 
else {
    NSLog(@"Not found");
}
```

Are you creating the file inside the App? Maybe that's where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry to ask this silly question... "attributesOfItemAtPath:path" How to initialise this "path" variable. suppose I am having a image named "icon_57.png" placed in the root  of project ?

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat here's a Swift implementation... should be easy enough to get the syntax for ObjC `let documentsDirectoryString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        return documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("icon_57.png")`

Answer (score 23):

There is a special message `fileCreationDate` for that in `NSDictionary`. The following works for me:

**Objective-C:**

```
NSDate *date = [attrs fileCreationDate];
```

**Swift:**

```
let attrs = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(path) as NSDictionary
attrs.fileCreationDate()
```

Comment: The swift version works fine but in swift 5 (at least) there is no method called `attrs.fileCreationDate()`, instead I used `attrs[.creationDate] as? Date` ...if you are wondering

Answer (score 11):

Updated answer for **Swift 4** to pull out the modified (`.modifiedDate`) or creation (`.creationDate`) date:

```
let file: URL = ...
if let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: file.path) as [FileAttributeKey: Any],
    let creationDate = attributes[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as? Date {
    print(creationDate)
    }
```

1. Using a file that you provide in advance via a URL, it will request its attributes. If successful a dictionary of [FileAttributeKey: Any] is returned
2. Using the dictionary from step 1, it then pulls out the creation date (or modified if you prefer) and using the conditional unwrap, assigns it to a date if successful
3. Assuming the first two steps are successful, you now have a date that you can work with

Answer (score 9):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
do {
    let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(YOURPATH)
    let creationDate = fileAttributes[NSFileCreationDate] as? NSDate
    let modificationDate = fileAttributes[NSFileModificationDate] as? NSDate
    print("creation date of file is", creationDate)
    print("modification date of file is", modificationDate)
}catch let error as NSError {
    print("file not found:", error)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 5:

```swift
let date = (try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path))?[.creationDate] as? Date
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4, if you want to know the file created date for a specific file in DocumentsDirectory, you can use this method

```
func getfileCreatedDate(theFile: String) -> Date {

        var theCreationDate = Date()
        do{
            let aFileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: theFile) as [FileAttributeKey:Any]
            theCreationDate = aFileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as! Date

        } catch let theError as Error{
            print("file not found \(theError)")
        }
        return theCreationDate
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  NSDate *creationDate = nil;
  if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
       NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
       creationDate = attributes[NSFileCreationDate];
  }
```

Its [here](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/)

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
let url: URL = ....
let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)
if let date = attributes?[.modificationDate] {
   print("File Modification date is %@", date)
}
if let date = attributes?[.creationDate] {
   print("File Creation date is %@", date)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 version code:

```
do {
        let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: yourPathString)
        let modificationDate = fileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.modificationDate] as! Date
        print("Modification date: ", modificationDate)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error getting file modification attribute date: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate if you could explain your answer too.

Comment: Use FileAttributeKey.creationDate if you want the file creation date as per the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [`fstat64`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html) to get the `st_birthtimespec` member of the returned struct? You'll need to create a C file handle for the file and convert the `timespec` value into an `NSDate`, but that's better than nothing.

Comment: No, you should not be able to use fstat64 owing to the fact that, to the best of my knowledge iPhone OS is not yet 64 bits. Unfortunately, in 32 bits mode, the  struct timespec st_birthtimespec is NOT available in struct stat. This is the reason why the NSDate object returned by [attrs fileCreationDate] will be always nil on the iPhone as of 3.1.2, where attrs is the NSDictionary containing the file attributes.

Comment: Thanks guys.   Looks like I'll just have to remember when the file was created and store it in NSUserDefaults.