# Get document directory files date modified time in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

```
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *currDircetory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:currDircetory  error:nil];
for (NSString *s in filePathsArray){
        NSLog(@"file %@", s);
}
```

Now i used the above code to get list of file from document directory now i want to know how to get modified time of the file in document directory.

Thanks,

Vijayan

Answer (score 11):

You can use this :

```
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *currDircetory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:currDircetory  error:nil];

for (NSString *s in filePathsArray){

    NSString *filestring = [currDircetory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",s];
    NSDictionary *filePathsArray1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filestring error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Modified Day : %@", [filePathsArray1 objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NSFileManager* filemngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSDictionary* attributes = [filemngr attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];

if (attributes != nil) {

    NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
} else {

    NSLog(@"File Not found !!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108953/ios-how-do-you-find-the-creation-date-of-a-file#answer-6428757).

But only change you going to do is, you need to change `NSFileCreationDate` to `NSFileModificationDate`

```
NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileModificationDate];
```